# How do you pass script arguments to pdb (Python)?

Tags: python, debugging, arguments, pdb

I've got python script (ala #! /usr/bin/python) and I want to debug it with pdb. How can I pass arguments to the script?

I have a python script and would like to debug it with pdb. Is there a way that I can pass arguments to the scripts?

Answer (score 29):

```
python -m pdb myscript.py arg1 arg2 ...
```

This invokes `pdb` as a script to debug another script. You can pass command-line arguments after the script name. See the [pdb doc page](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

usually I use ipython

```
-i
    If running code from the command line, become interactive afterwards.
    It is often useful to follow this with `--` to treat remaining flags as
    script arguments.


ipython --pdb -i -- test.py -a
```

Answer (score 1):

`python3 -m pdb myscript.py -a val` if using argparse with flag "a" and value "val"

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you prefer the more graphical [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) debugger, you can pass the arguments of your script directly by doing:

```
pudb myscript.py arg1 arg2 ...
```

Indeed, invoking:

```
 python -m pudb myscript.py arg1 arg2 ...
```

won't work will return with the following error:

```
No module named pudb.__main__; 'pudb' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```